# I have problem with build apk with kivymd

Tags: android, kivy, kivymd

I don't know what to write in the **requirements.**

main.py

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel

class Screen(MDApp):
  def build(self):
    return MDLabel(text='helllo')

Screen().run()
```

I write **requirements=python3, kivy, kivymd, pillow**
also I tried **requirements=kivy==2.1.0, kivymd==1.2.0**
but The program won't run.

Answer (score 0):

Use better, kivy==2.3.0 and kivymd==1.1.1, if you keep going with kivymd 1.2.0, buildozer going to try to install de latest version and it's still in dev, and give you an error with the permission for pip.
Don't forget to add in the requirements python and pillow.